# How accurate is MemAvailable from /proc/meminfo?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management

While the difference between `MemFree` and `MemAvailable` has been asked before ([What is the difference between MemFree and MemAvailable in /proc/meminfo](https://superuser.com/q/980820/1027955)), the answers and articles (for example https://topic.alibabacloud.com/a/the-difference-between-linux-memfree-and-memavailable_1_16_30151791.html) always indicate that `MemAvailable` is an estimate.  That seems to imply that there is a certain inaccuracy in `MemAvailable`.

Could someone please explain why it is an estimate, where and how big the inaccuracies are and whether `MemAvailable` rather tends to underestimate or overestimate the available memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [page_alloc.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/mm/page_alloc.c#L5146) source below you can see the estimate part of the calculation is what proportion of the page cache and reclaimable slab memory can be freed without causing swapping.  In both cases at least half (or the low watermark from `/proc/zoneinfo` if more) is assumed to be needed.

Therefore the limit of any "inaccuracy" for each can only be between low watermark and assuming *all* can be freed which certainly isn't true.

Whether half (as opposed to 1/4 or 3/4 say) is a fair assumption would depend on your system and usage - from the [original commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=34e431b0ae398fc54ea69ff85ec700722c9da773)

> It is wrong because Cached includes memory that is not freeable as page
>   cache, for example shared memory segments, tmpfs, and ramfs, and it does
>   not include reclaimable slab memory, which can take up a large fraction
>   of system memory on mostly idle systems with lots of files.

In this *Unix & Linux* question, [How can I get the amount of available memory portably across distributions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261247/how-can-i-get-the-amount-of-available-memory-portably-across-distributions), comments indicate calculating it gives larger values than reading from `/proc/meminfo` but this needn't always be true.

```
long si_mem_available(void)
{
    long available;
    unsigned long pagecache;
    unsigned long wmark_low = 0;
    unsigned long pages[NR_LRU_LISTS];
    unsigned long reclaimable;
    struct zone *zone;
    int lru;

    for (lru = LRU_BASE; lru < NR_LRU_LISTS; lru++)
        pages[lru] = global_node_page_state(NR_LRU_BASE + lru);

    for_each_zone(zone)
        wmark_low += low_wmark_pages(zone);

    /*
     * Estimate the amount of memory available for userspace allocations,
     * without causing swapping.
     */
    available = global_zone_page_state(NR_FREE_PAGES) - totalreserve_pages;

    /*
     * Not all the page cache can be freed, otherwise the system will
     * start swapping. Assume at least half of the page cache, or the
     * low watermark worth of cache, needs to stay.
     */
    pagecache = pages[LRU_ACTIVE_FILE] + pages[LRU_INACTIVE_FILE];
    pagecache -= min(pagecache / 2, wmark_low);
    available += pagecache;

    /*
     * Part of the reclaimable slab and other kernel memory consists of
     * items that are in use, and cannot be freed. Cap this estimate at the
     * low watermark.
     */
    reclaimable = global_node_page_state(NR_SLAB_RECLAIMABLE) +
            global_node_page_state(NR_KERNEL_MISC_RECLAIMABLE);
    available += reclaimable - min(reclaimable / 2, wmark_low);

    if (available < 0)
        available = 0;
    return available;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(si_mem_available);
```